# Node.js Server-Side HTTP request to ASP script

Tags: asp.net, node.js, http, httpcookie

Currently building an application in node.js. I am trying to make a server-side HTTP request to an ASP script and return the results.

If I navigate to the url in my browser, everything is fine. Data is returned. However, when I do this in node.js using restler, or any other module for that matter. I get nothing back......UNTIL I add the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie to the header of the request. I copied this cookie from the successul GET from my browser.

How do I get/set this session cookie server-side in node.js?

Using express framework. Code below.

app.js

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser('cat'));
  app.use(express.session());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

route index.js

```
/*
 * GET home page.
 */

exports.index = function(req, res){

    var http = require("http"),
    sys = require('util'),
    rest = require('restler');

    rest.get('http://192.168.154.134/dca/stream/StreamDown.asp?' +
        'Action=GetRepositoryConnections' , {headers:{
        'Cookie':'ASP.NET_SessionId=jj1jx255wlkwib45gq0d3555;' +
        ' ASPSESSIONIDASDDSBQR=ACABCJNDIIONGGMPGAOMMJJD;' +
        ' ASPSESSIONIDCQQRQDQR=BAIBCEODMMKAPJAOLLMMDNEJ;' +
        ' ASPSESSIONIDAQSTRAQR=KMLDIOODECFNBKPGINLLNBKC;' +
        ' ASPSESSIONIDASQQQDQR=OKGBKCPDHDIKAJNOGFKACCCG'}

    }).on('complete', function(result) {

        if (result instanceof Error) {
            sys.puts('Error: ' + result.message);
            this.retry(5000); // try again after 5 sec
        } else {
            sys.puts(result);
        }
    });

    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });

};
```

Comment: Does that ASP page require some authentication?

Comment: No authentication is required.

Answer (score 0):

Try [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request). It has a "cookie jar" so it will remember cookies for you.

Comment: How to do I get that session cookie from the server for the first request though to store it? That is where I am struggling.

Comment: Maybe you should just make an initial request to the homepage and that should give you a cookie.